# Tab+NavigationController flow

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've got a tabbar controller as a main screen in my app. Some of the tabs got navigation controller embedded.

Here is my problem:
First tab is the initial one when app starts. Under certain conditions user should see second screen B (on navigation stack) immediately after app starts (there is performSegue which triggers in viewWillAppear of first screen). This works as it should. User starts the app and immediately sees the second screen. This also works when user switches to different tab and back. The problem is when user already is on the first tab and taps on it again. Then the stack gets destroyed users sees first screen A which will animate into second screen B in short order. This transition is clearly visible by user.

```
First tab --> screen A --> screen B --> ...
|
Second tab --> screen T --> screen U --> ...
|
...
```

So the question is how to prevent this behaviour? User shouldn't see the transition between A and B in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the expected behavior of `UITabBarController`, it will pop the navigation controller to the first view controller in its stack.

If you don't want the screen A to appear under certain conditions when user taps the tab bar item, just remove the first view controller from the navigation stack, doing something like this after pushing from A to B (form instance in the viewDidLoad: of B view controller):

```
NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: navigationController.viewControllers];
[allViewControllers removeObjectAtIndex: 0];
navigationController.viewControllers = allViewControllers;
```

This way screen B will be the root view controller of your navigation stack, which is what you want.

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem very consistent behaviour of uitabbarcontroller since it will only pop the controller on the second tap. Anyway that certain condition will change again so I would have put it back as root controller

Comment: It's just a way to let users navigate straight to root VC, and certainly I find it useful. Anyway, you can keep a reference to the removed view controller in your uitabbarcontroller to put it back when you want

Comment: You are right. In the end it was the solution I used. When the condition changes I put A back the root and it actually works quite nicely... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change your code from Screen A to perfrom segue to next next Screen B unser CERTAIN condition.,

Just use that CERTAINcondition in TabbarController Class ( Subclass of Tabbar) in method  like,

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0)
    {  
         if (CERTAIN condition True) {
              UITabBar tabbar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
              NSArray *controlrs = self.viewControllers; 
              NSMutableArray *controllerCopy = [controlrs mutablecopy];
              SCREEN_B_class *bClassObj =  . .. //Tab 1 class Just Screen B, not Screen A -> ScreenB
              [controllerCopy replaceObjectsAtIndex:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:bClassObj]]
              tabBarController.viewControllers = controllerCopy;

         }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps you,

HTH, Enjoy Coding!!